# Creating a Results Grid from a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following table of results in a *Pandas DataFrame*. Each player has been assigned an ID number:

```
+----------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
| Home Player ID | Away Player ID | Home Points | Away Points |
+----------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
|              1 |              2 |           3 |           0 |
|              3 |              4 |           1 |           1 |
|              2 |              3 |           3 |           0 |
|              4 |              1 |           3 |           0 |
|              2 |              4 |           1 |           1 |
|              3 |              1 |           1 |           1 |
|              2 |              1 |           0 |           3 |
|              4 |              3 |           1 |           1 |
|              3 |              2 |           0 |           3 |
|              1 |              4 |           0 |           3 |
|              4 |              2 |           1 |           1 |
|              1 |              3 |           1 |           1 |
+----------------+----------------+-------------+-------------+
```

The aim is to create a 4x4 *numpy* matrix (dimensions equal to the number of players) and fill the matrix with the points they earned from games between the respective players.

The matrix should end up like this:

```
+--------+---+---+---+---+
| Matrix | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
+--------+---+---+---+---+
|      1 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
|      2 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 1 |
|      3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
|      4 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
+--------+---+---+---+---+
```

The left hand column is the ID number of the home players, with the column headers the IDs of the away players.

For example, when the Home Player ID = 1 and the Away Player ID = 2, Player 1 earned 3 points, so the entry for the Matrix(1,2) *(or 0,1 because of the zero indexing)* would equal 3.

I can just about manage to do this with two for loops, but it seems quite inefficient. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Would really appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
In [217]: df.pivot_table(columns='Home Player ID', index='Away Player ID', 
                         values='Away Points', fill_value=0)
Out[217]:
Home Player ID  1  2  3  4
Away Player ID
1               0  3  1  0
2               0  0  3  1
3               1  0  0  1
4               3  1  1  0
```

Or use

```
In [221]: df.set_index(['Away Player ID', 'Home Player ID'])['Away Points'].unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[221]:
Home Player ID  1  2  3  4
Away Player ID
1               0  3  1  0
2               0  0  3  1
3               1  0  0  1
4               3  1  1  0
```